# Is there a way to define an 'int' by 'greater/lesser than' instead of '='?

Tags: c++, int

I was playing around in a challenge on some website, and I met this problem.
i have an unidentified integer  ... only I know that it is greater that x or\and lesser that y and so on ... 
is there a way to define a variable based on so? ...
I mean as being greater\lesser than integer ..

some have noted that not_null would help but I couldn't understand how ..

here is some silly example :

```cpp
int some_unknown_number > 8;
if [some_unknown_number<=1] 
    {cout << "wrong" << endl;}
```

so I expect the code to recognize that some_unknown_number can't be lesser than 1 since it's already larger than 8....

ps: I don't want the exact answer ... just tell me where to look if you know what I mean ....

Comment: `int` can only be one specific integer. It sounds like you have a range of possible values. It's not clear what you want to do with the `some_unknown_number`, so I need more details to be able to help.

Comment: `=` is pronounced "assign", not "equal to"

Comment: You may define your own type with such requirement

Comment: I don want to do anything with some_unknown_number except checking some logical statments like being larger or lesser than some numbers based on another logical statments ...

Answer (score 4):

You could build a class representing this as

```
struct bounded
{
    std::optional<int> m_lower;
    std::optional<int> m_higher;
};
```

which models the lower and upper bound of an instance. If both are present and set to the same value, this clearly models a plain `int`.

You then build your `<` operator &c. in accordance with this model.

Comment: bonus points: include `counting_iterator begin()` and `counting_iterator end()`, and get for loops with all the numbers that satisfy the condition

Comment: I dont have an exact range ... just the higher or the lower limit of the range ...
Would that work if I have only one of them?

Comment: @Andrew_Jacop: Of course, that's why I use `std::optional`.

Comment: @Andrew_Jacop yes, you'd use `m_lower.value_or(std::numeric_limits<int>::min())` and `m_higher.value_or(std::numeric_limits<int>::max())` in comparisons

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, indeed. You can define your type. For example:

```
template<int Min, int Max>
struct Int
{
  static_assert(Max > Min, "Max should be greater than Min");

  bool operator<(int val) const
  {
    return val > Max;
  }

  bool operator>(int val) const
  {
    return Min > val;
  }
};
```

You can add more operators, if needed, to define necessary semantics, and use it like:

```
// Int<19, 1> wrongInt; <--- compile time error.

Int<1, 3> myInt;
if (myInt > 0)
  printf("Greater than 0\n");

if (myInt < 5)
  printf("Less than 5\n");
```

Comment: Why template parameters?

Comment: @Caleth, because `Int<1, 3>` is a new type. A static type.

Comment: You don't need the members `m_min` and `m_max`. In fact you ruin `constexpr` if you keep them. Nice idea though. Getting ready to upvote.

Comment: same question as the previous answer ... 
would that work if I have only one limit ? I have either the 'max' or the 'min' ... not both

Comment: Yes, but it's a type with only one value. And quite likely you'd want to have run-time values here

Comment: @Andrew_Jacop, you can modify the class to have only one template parameter: max or min.

Comment: cool ... 
well .. since I don't understand about 96.6578% ( I actually calculated that :D ) of what your answer since I'm a total noob ...
I'll start searching into that answer of yours and try it out then I'll be back to you with the vote shortly ... :)

Comment: @vahancho: But you don't need them at all, just use `Max` and `Min`.